# Show group on every record in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am using pandas and `groupby` to aggregate. I'm doing the following:

```
data = {'ac' : ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'],
        'cls'   ['wwww','wwww','wwww','xxxx','xxxx','zzzz','zzzz','yyyy','wwww','xxxx','zzzz','zzzz','yyyy'],
        'pl' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped = df.groupby(['ac','cls']).agg({'pl':np.sum})


           pl
    ac cls     
    a  wwww   3
       xxxx   2
       yyyy   1
       zzzz   2
    b  wwww   1
       xxxx   1
       yyyy   1
       zzzz   2
```

Is there a way to do the `groupby` where it will fill in the `ac` column so that it reads like the following?

```
             pl
    ac cls     
    a  wwww   3
    a  xxxx   2
    a  yyyy   1
    a  zzzz   2
    b  wwww   1
    b  xxxx   1
    b  yyyy   1
    b  zzzz   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to reset the index:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

data = {'ac': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'],
        'cls': ['wwww','wwww','wwww','xxxx','xxxx','zzzz','zzzz','yyyy','wwww','xxxx','zzzz','zzzz','yyyy'],
        'pl': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped = df.groupby(['ac','cls']).agg({'pl':np.sum})
grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)

print grouped
```

This prints:

```
  ac   cls  pl
0  a  wwww   3
1  a  xxxx   2
2  a  yyyy   1
3  a  zzzz   2
4  b  wwww   1
5  b  xxxx   1
6  b  yyyy   1
7  b  zzzz   2
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize (though I should have) that the groupby created new indices, and that a simple reset_index would fix it.  I'm marking this one as the answer that solved my problem, even though both do, because it keeps the operation strictly to the dataframe in question, rather than as a global setting.

Comment: You can basically get the same result but without the extra column using the `level` option:  `grouped.reset_index(level=0)`

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly showing that the items on the left are in the index as indicated by the position of the column header to the right.

This is controlled with a pandas option called [**`display.multi_sparse`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).  You can turn it off with `pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)` or you can do it temporarily with `pd.option_context`

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(grouped)

         pl
ac cls     
a  wwww   3
a  xxxx   2
a  yyyy   1
a  zzzz   2
b  wwww   1
b  xxxx   1
b  yyyy   1
b  zzzz   2
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize (though I should have) that the groupby created new indices, and that a simple reset_index would fix it.  I'm marking this one as the answer that solved my problem, even though both do, because it keeps the operation strictly to the dataframe in question, rather than as a global setting.

Comment: @BinoyFernandez it's clear that asongtoruin got at what you really needed.  But I wanted to provide an answer to your actual question so that others looking it up might find it beneficial.  Also, notice that the other solution doesn't reproduce your stated results.  It can't without leaving the columns in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as_index=True`

```
In [748]: df.groupby(['ac', 'cls'], as_index=False).agg({'pl': np.sum})
Out[748]:
  ac   cls  pl
0  a  wwww   3
1  a  xxxx   2
2  a  yyyy   1
3  a  zzzz   2
4  b  wwww   1
5  b  xxxx   1
6  b  yyyy   1
7  b  zzzz   2
```